# React make bootstrap work through importing

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I import bootstrap styles

```
import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
```

Then i create a simple container

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div  className="col-6">
       23423423
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
      234234234
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Bootstrap does not apply styles to my container, it feels like it's not actually even imported.
I see bootstrap in my node_modules so im sure it's 
installed correctly, no errors in console, nothing
If i import bootstrap through `link`, then it's working fine, why it's not working with import

Here's my dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
"css-loader": "^3.2.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
"file-loader": "^4.2.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"precss": "^4.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
"style-loader": "^1.0.0",
"typescript": "^3.6.2",
"webpack": "^4.39.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"less": "^3.10.3",
"mobx-react": "^6.1.3",
"popper.js": "^1.15.0",
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"sass": "^1.22.10"
}
```

My webpack

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: {
                            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => {
                            return [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Edit**: after i import bootstrap.scss it adds bootstrap fonts to body, if it's imported and it works fine, then why styles for container and columns not working

Answer (score 0):

based on https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader you may have missed the following: npm i -D node-sass

- check if there is any console error after build
- check if you can find the css style reference to bootstrap.scss from the dom using Chrome

Comment: i added node-sass, but it didn't work anyways, i can find reference to bootstrap styles in console, Bootstrap set me custom fonts, paddings and so on, but it's not working for columns, container etc

Comment: You may need to double-check where the style comes from as if you had imported bootstrap in components on higher-order it may have inherited from there. If that's not the case then I'd suggest to manually import grid style from cdn and see if it's working.

Comment: I've found where's the problem, it happends after i add localIdentName to my css-loader, if i delete this one bootstrap is working fine. Still don't understrand how to work around this